# Is there a way to run a single cucumber scenario outline in parallel?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, junit4

I am working on a simple exercise for selenium testing using cucumber BDD. I had written my scenario for one piece of test data and was converting it to allow for multiple pieces of test data to be run through my steps. I have used a scenario outline and excel sheet to read the test data and it executes each one by one, which obviously is taking time. I was wondering if it is possible to run each example for a scenario outline in parallel or if there is another way i should be trying to run through multiple pieces of test data.

Feature File:

```
 Feature Insurance Quote - User is wanting to acquire a green slip quote
for their current vehicle.

Scenario Outline: User wants to generate insurance quote
Given I'm on the homepage
And I navigate to getting a quote in NSW
When I select quote type from excel <rowIndex>
And I enter my vehicle details
And I enter insurance preferences from excel <rowIndex>
Then I'll be provided with a quote and test <rowIndex> passed

Examples:
|rowIndex  |
|1         |
|2         |
|3         |
|4         |
```

My step definitions and test runner all work fine as i can run through the scenario all working correctly, just is does each excel row one by one and i want to find a way to be able to execute them in parallel.

Any advise would be great thanks.

Comment: if u are using a version greater than 4 check this https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/ To run each row of a scenario outline in different threads u can run it by using a testng runner or through command line. JUnit runners will run feature file in parallel rather than scenarios and scenario outline in a single file.

Comment: Well said @grasshopper and huge thanks for sharing link which has lots of information about parallel execution.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I was able to use it to get my project to run in parallel